# Updating a ToolbarWindow32 save path with VBA through the Win API

Tags: vba, winapi, excel

I'm trying to change the save path in a Google Chrome download window from Excel's VBA through the Windows API. i.e. the part marked "temp" in the screenshot below needs to be updated before the Save button is clicked.

[image]

I can find the toolbar that it's in without a problem with the code below.

```
downloadWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")
subWindow = FindWindowEx(downloadWindow, ByVal 0&, "WorkerW", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "ReBarWindow32", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "Address Band Root", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "msctls_progress32", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "Breadcrumb Parent", vbNullString)
savePath = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "ToolbarWindow32", vbNullString)
```

The problem is with updating the path. I have tried doing it with the SendMessage command below, but that doesn't work.

```
SendMessageByString savePath, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "C:\newpath"
```

How can I update the path?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to solve the same problem all day and I've just discovered that you don't need to change the toolbar path. You can just set the full file path into the file name box and it will save to the desired location.

```
downloadWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")
subWindow = FindWindowEx(downloadWindow, ByVal 0&, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "DirectUIHWND", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "FloatNotifySink", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
subWindow = FindWindowEx(subWindow, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)

Dim FullPath As String
FullPath = "C:\myfolder\myfile.xyz"
Call SendMessage(subWindow, WM_SETTEXT, False, ByVal FullPath )
```

You'll need to include the Sendmessage function along with the FindWindowEx function if you haven't done so already

```
Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish you had answered this a few years ago :)